# How do I use npm modules in jasmine tests?

Tags: html, node.js, jasmine

I want to us a npm module (as a simple example here `array-equal`

This is my jasmine test spec:

```
describe('BinoxxoController', function() {
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('binoxxoapp'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;

}));

describe('$scope.lineIsValid', function() {
    var $scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function() {
        $scope = {};

        var controller = $controller('BinoxxoController', { $scope: $scope});

    })


    it('equals array', function() {
        var array0 = [1, 2, 3];
        var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
        expect(equal(array0, array1)).toBe(true);

    });


});
```

});

index.html (testrunner)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <script src="../../../static/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../node_modules/array-equal/index.js"></script>

    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="spec/controllerSpec.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I included the module, but i still get an error `ReferenceError: equal is not defined`

Here is the array-equal module if that helps:

```
module.exports = function equal(arr1, arr2) {
  var length = arr1.length
  if (length !== arr2.length) return false
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
      return false
  return true
}
```

I can confirm that the path to the src file is correct and all js files are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Require the module within your jasmine spec.

```
describe('$scope.lineIsValid', function() {
    var $scope,
        controller,
        yourModule = require('array-equal);
```

then

```
expect(yourModule.equal(array0, array1)).toBe(true);
```